# Generating PAdES-LT signature(CMSSignedData) using bouncy castle without DSS

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pades

I have code which generates PAdES-B CMSSignedData.

After this I am including timestamp in usigned attributes which is making CMSSignedData PAdES-T.

How can I make it PAdES-LT? Where should we include revocation information?

Thanks in advance.

Code to generate PAdES-B CMSSignedData

```
private CMSSignedDataGenerator getCmsSignedDataGenerator(ElectronicSignatureModel signatureModel) {
        CMSSignedDataGenerator signGenerator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        signGenerator.addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(signatureModel.getChain()));
        ContentSigner nonSigner = new ContentSigner() {

            @Override
            public byte[] getSignature() {
                return signatureModel.getSignature();
            }

            @Override
            public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
                return new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            }

            @Override
            public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
                return new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder()
                        .find(signatureModel.getSigningAlgorithm().getAlgoName());
            }
        };

        JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder signerBuilder = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build());
        signerBuilder.setDirectSignature(true);
       
        //user certificate
        Certificate userCertHolder = Certificate.getInstance(ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(
                signatureModel.getChain().get(0).getEncoded()));
        signGenerator.addSignerInfoGenerator(signerBuilder.build(nonSigner, new X509CertificateHolder(userCertHolder)));
        return signGenerator;
    }
CMSSignedDataGenerator signGenerator = getCmsSignedDataGenerator(signatureModel, false);
CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = signGenerator.generate(new CMSProcessableByteArray(signatureModel.getSignature()), false);
```

Comment: *"Where should we include revocation information?"* - You don't include them in the signature container. Instead you build specific pdf objects to hold them. Simply take a look at the specifications in question.

Comment: For CAdES-LT we include revocation information in signed attributes.
This will make signature LTV enabled in PDF when embedded.

Code: 

ASN1EncodableVector revocationInfo = new ASN1EncodableVector();
            revocationInfo.add(new DERTaggedObject(true, 1, new DERSequence(data.getOcsps())));
            signedAttributes.add(new Attribute(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier(SIGNER_ATTR_ADOBE_REVOCATION_INFO_IDENTIFIER),
                    new DERSet(new DERSequence(revocationInfo))));

Comment: "LTV enabled" is different from "PAdES-LT". The former (non-standard, Adobe proprietary) profile accepts revocation information in many places. "PAdES-LT" requires them in DSS sections in the PDF.

Comment: okay noted. 
So where to include revocation information if I have to make it LTV enabled?
Since PAdES does not have signed attributes in my case(signerBuilder.setDirectSignature(true)) where shall we include revocation data?

Comment: Which do you want? You mention both "LTV enabled" and "PAdES" while - as said before - they are completely different.

Comment: how to make signature in PDF "LTV enabled"?

Comment: If you need to add the revocation information in the signature container, use the Adobe `RevocationInfoArchival` signed attribute as specified in the PDF specification. But according to your first comment here you already know that attribute (even though you mention it for CAdES-LT which is wrong of course).

Comment: I am setting signerBuilder.setDirectSignature(true);. Signed attributes will not be included. 
In this case where shall we include revocation information to make the signature LTV enabled?

Comment: There are two interoperable options where to put revocation information in a signed PDF, either the `RevocationInfoArchival` signed attribute or the DSS section. I've not tested whether Adobe Acrobat supports other locations for revocation information. Even if it does, though, that might be just transiently.

Comment: does adding 'PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_ets_revocationValues' attribute in unsigned attributes make the signature LTV enabled?

Comment: Most likely not. That attribute is neither specified or referenced ifor use n the PDF specification nor in the PAdES specification. So if it was supported by Adobe Acrobat, that support would not be backed by any specification.